# Android Imageview disappears and degrades when rotate

Tags: android, animation, layout, rotation, imageview

In my app I have an Imageview (My picture is a 30 ko PNG) that I rotate. On Samsung Galaxy S3, S5 and Note I don't have any problems like on android simulator. But on my Nexus 5 (on android 4.4.4) when the imageview rotate, it degrades and disappears and i don't know why ?

[Image on Samsung and Simulator after rotation](http://postimg.org/image/3vbv1nnzx/)
.

[Image on Nexus 5 after rotation](http://postimg.org/image/71a8x5vcj/)
.

The rotation code is in a thread

```
RotateAnimation ranim = new RotateAnimation(
0f, oscillationDegrees, 
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,                         
Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
ranim.setDuration(1000);
ranim.setFillAfter(true); //keep the position after rotation
Picture.startAnimation(ranim);
```

Layout

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/LN"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:src="@drawable/h_baro_ln" />
```

I try to put my Imageview in a Linearlayout and rotate it instead of the imageview but it's again the same problem.

Do you have some ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: RotateAnimation is an **Animation**, it is not designed for rotating your ImageView but to animate it

Comment: I animate my ImageView with a rotation and an oscillation and to finish I keep the final position. It's working on Emulator, Samsung S3, S5, Note, but not on Nexus 5 and this is just a mystery for me ....

Comment: if you want to rotate your ImageView use scale type == matrix and rotate the Matrix

Comment: I have the same problem, on my Motorola G on Android 4.4.4. When i launch animation (translate/scale/rotate) on a imageview AND with admob banner showed at the bottom of the screen. When admob banner is not displayed, the rotation works fine...